# Does C varargs use a keyword called 'end'?

Tags: c, windows, winapi, variadic-functions

I have a lot of code that uses C style variable arguments. The code passes in a variable called **end** at the very end of our variable length function calls. And.... the code also has an enumerator called **end**. So far they haven't clashed (compiler error says it has an ambiguous definition: It won't tell me where the mysterious second 'end' is defined) until I changed to the VC 10.0 compiler (VS 2010).

So is **end** some sort of reserved keyword used especially in variable args? 
I know very little about them. But I've looked at tons of documentation on variable arguments, as well as searching here, and found nothing (which could be a good thing). So I would guess the answer is that **end** is not a special word used with varargs. Can I get someone to confirm this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No -- C doesn't define `end` as having any special meaning with varargs. When you write a function that takes a variable argument list, it's up to you to decide how to tell it how long of a list has been passed. Some popular ones are that the first argument specifies (at least indirectly) how many more arguments there are, and passing a "sentinel" value (e.g., NULL) after all the others. For a couple of examples, `printf` does the former, `execl` the latter.

Comment: `execl`, surely. Anyway, that brings up the other problem - execl only can work that way because _all_ of its arguments [including NULL] are the same type: `char *`. This question's `end` can only work if it is the same type as the other arguments that his function are expecting.

Comment: And it's not: 'end' in my code is just at the end of a long user defined enumeration list. So it's not anywhere near being a char*.

Answer (score 4):

Once upon a long time ago (7th Edition Unix, for example), there were three external symbols defined: `etext`, `edata` and `end`.  These corresponded to the upper address of the code, the initialized data and the heap.  It may be that your definition of `end` is colliding with that, somehow.