# variadic functions with `fcn( char *, ...)` how does it know when to end?

Tags: c, printf, variadic-functions, kernighan-and-ritchie

I've been reviewing stuff from multiple sources including my old favorite K&R second ed.

I've been looking at variadic functions, and almost all the tutorials I've seen use and `int` before the ellipses to determine the total number variable arguments passed.

But K&R example in the book does not use an `int`, they uses a `char *`

I searched stackoverflow and found stuff like:

> Any variadic function must have a way for the caller to specify the
>   number and types of arguments. The *printf functions, for example, do
>   so via the (non-variadic) format string.
>   [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37356030/how-to-determine-the-end-of-va-arg-list)

and

> No -- C doesn't define end as having any special meaning with varargs.
>   When you write a function that takes a variable argument list, it's up
>   to you to decide how to tell it how long of a list has been passed.
>   [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5747238/does-c-varargs-use-a-keyword-called-end)

K&R minprintf is meant to show how to use variadic function.

> ---- to show how to write a function that processes a variable-length
>   argument list in a portable way. Since we are mainly interested in the
>   argument processing, minprintf will process the format string and
>   arguments but will call the real printf to do the format conversions

K&R only show the function, I added the main at the bottom, to see if it would work. I compiled it with `gcc -Wall test.c`. It compiled with no warnings, and worked as expected. The code is:

```
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdio.h>

/* minprintf: minimal printf with variable argument list */
void minprintf(char *fmt, ...)
{
   va_list ap; /* points to each unnamed arg in turn */
   char *p, *sval;
   int ival;
   double dval;

   va_start(ap, fmt); /* make ap point to 1st unnamed arg */
   for (p = fmt; *p; p++) {
      if (*p != '%') {
         putchar(*p);
         continue;
      }
      switch (*++p) {
      case 'd':
         ival = va_arg(ap, int);
         printf("%d", ival);
         break;
      case 'f':
         dval = va_arg(ap, double);
         printf("%f", dval);
         break;
      case 's':
         for (sval = va_arg(ap, char *); *sval; sval++)
            putchar(*sval);
         break;
      default:
         putchar(*p);
         break;
      }
   }
   va_end(ap); /* clean up when done */
}
// I added this main below to test K&R minprintf function. It compiled no errors and gave right answer.

int main()
{
   int i = 25;
   int j = 21;
   char str[] = "This is a test";
   minprintf("%d, %d, %s\n", i, j, str);
}
```

How does `minprintf` know when to end? Is there a `NULL` in there? K&R do not explain it. From the stuff I read on-line, and some of the quotes above, a variadic functions does not know where to end, unless you tell it, such as with an int before the ellipses.

Comment: Since you said the problem was you not knowing that strings end with `\0`, then this had nothing to do with variadic functions to begin with. You confused the amount of arguments passed to a variadic function with the amount of characters in a string.

Comment: @ HolyBlackCat I know that if I do `a[] = " text"`  add null, but the `(char *, ...)` confused me. K&R `getline` does not add NULL, so you don't always get a NULL. You can add it at the end or not. Also every other example online, and in a book i have use and `int` to determine size.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is a `\0` in there. Look at the terminating condition of the loop:

```
for (p = fmt; *p; p++) { // look here
    // ...
}
```

When `p` does not point to a `\0` value, `*p != '\0'`, i.e. `(bool)*p` is `true`. In this case, `*p` is processed, be it a `%`, or something else.

When `p` points to a `\0` value, `(bool)*p` is `false`. The loop ends, and the `va_end` is called.

Therefore, after it has scanned over the string, processed all `%` specifiers, it terminates by checking *the end of the string*.

Comment: How did the NULL get put into the fcn?  He has `(char *, ...)` Many times if i write my own string, I have to manually add `'\0'` to the end.

Comment: Or does `char *` add it for you?

Comment: @Manny_Mar When you use a string literal, like `"abc"`, it automatically gets `\0` at  the end. Compare with `char` arrays, like `char arr[3] = {'a', 'b', 'c'};`, which don't get `\0` automatically.

Comment: @Manny_Mar C-strings automatically end with `\0`. `"%d, %d, %s\n"` automatically adds a `\0` at the end.

Comment: @Manny_Mar You can read the first paragraph on [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte) page to get more information.

Comment: @ L. F OK, did not realize it added the NULL. Then i see how it ends.

Comment: @Gerhardh That makes sense. I will tweak my wording.